React TanStack table not filtering subRow data
So i've recently ran into a problem regarding the filtering in an expandable tanstack react table that handles a one to many realtionship.
The problem is that basically, I have a globalFilter state and when I search, it only filters the root rows (which I don't want) and does nothing with the subrows. I've set filterFromLeafRows to true but it is not working.
Here is my table instance:
 const tableInstance = useReactTable({
columns: columnDef,
data: data,
filterFromLeafRows: true,
getSubRows: (row) => row.subRows,
getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
onPaginationChange: setPagination,
getExpandedRowModel: getExpandedRowModel(),
getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
onExpandedChange: setExpanded,
onGlobalFilterChange: setGlobalFilter,
state: {
  //...
  pagination,
  expanded,
  columnVisibility,
  globalFilter,
},

});
Here is my column definition:
const columnDef = [
{
  accessorKey: "Administracion",
  header: "Administración",
  cell: ({ row, getValue }) => (
    <div key={row.id}>
      <strong>{getValue()}</strong>
      {row.getCanExpand() && (
        <button
          key={row.id}
          className={"btn btn-outline-light ms-2"}
          style={{ border: "none" }}
          onClick={row.getToggleExpandedHandler()}
        >
          <FontAwesomeIcon
            icon={row.getIsExpanded() ? faChevronDown : faChevronRight}
          />
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  ),
},
{
  accessorKey: "Edif_ID",
  header: "Edif_ID",
},
{
  accessorKey: "Nombre",
  header: "Nombre",
},
{
  accessorKey: "Direccion",
  header: "Dirección",
},
{
  header: "Acciones",
  cell: ({ row }) => (
    <>
      {!row.getCanExpand() && (
        <div className="d-flex flex-row">
          <OverlayTrigger
            placement="top"
            overlay={
              <Tooltip id="tooltip">
                <strong>Administrar</strong>
              </Tooltip>
            }
          >
            <Button
              className={"btn btn-warning me-2"}
              onClick={() =>
                navigate("administrar/" + row.original.Edif_ID + "/info")
              }
            >
              {" "}
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faGear} />
            </Button>
          </OverlayTrigger>
          <OverlayTrigger
            placement="top"
            overlay={
              <Tooltip id="tooltip">
                <strong>Reservar</strong>
              </Tooltip>
            }
          >
            <Button
              className={"btn btn-success ms-3"}
              onClick={() =>
                navigate(
                  "/dashboard/misedificios/reservar/" + row.original.Edif_ID
                )
              }
            >
              {" "}
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faClock} />
            </Button>
          </OverlayTrigger>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  ),
},

];
Here is a data sample:
    [
  {
    "Adm_ID": "2",
    "Administracion": "Waven Solutions",
    "subRows": [
      {
        "Edif_ID": "4",
        "Nombre": "Cooperativa Cololó",
        "Direccion": "Liber Arce 3222",
        "Adm_ID": "2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Adm_ID": "3",
    "Administracion": "CQSoft",
    "subRows": [
      {
        "Edif_ID": "5",
        "Nombre": "Edificio Requena",
        "Direccion": "Joaquin Requena 917",
        "Adm_ID": "3"
      }
    ]
  }
]

a screenshot of the table without filtering:

and this is the table searching "a", showing the parent rows as subrows which I don't want:


Put this into the options in the useReactTable hook:
filterFromLeafRows: true
Here is the documentation for it:
https://tanstack.com/table/latest/docs/api/features/global-filtering#filterfromleafrows
